# How to show that $\int_M(\Delta f-|\nabla f|^2)(2\Delta f-|\nabla f|^2)e^{-f} dV=\int_M-\nabla_if\nabla_i(2\Delta f-|\nabla f|^2)e^{-f}dV$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

$M$ is a compact Riemannian manifold. $f$ is function on $M$

How to show that $\int_M(\Delta f-|\nabla f|^2)(2\Delta f-|\nabla f|^2)e^{-f} dV=\int_M-\nabla_if\nabla_i(2\Delta f-|\nabla f|^2)e^{-f}dV$?

I feel I should use integration by parts, but failed.

Thanks for any useful hint or answer.

Below picture is from 201th page of this [paper](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ajm/1154098947).
[image]

Comment: This can't be true for all $f$ and $H$.  If it were, you could let $u$ be arbitrary, write down the equation for $f=u$ and $H\equiv 2$, write it again for $f=2u$ and $H\equiv 1$, and subtract. This yields $\int_M |\nabla u|^2 dV=0$, which implies $u$ is constant on each component of $M$. Is there some relation between $f$ and $H$ you're not telling us about?

Comment: @JackLee $H=(2\Delta f-|\nabla f|^2)e^{-f}$, because the equality is used for different H,so I use the H replace the terms.I have added it in question.

Comment: $\nabla f$ is $\nabla_if\partial_i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is integration by part, (or divergence theorem):

Write $H = 2\Delta f-|\nabla f|^2$, then
$$\begin{split}
\int_M \Delta f H e^{-f} dV & = -\int_M \nabla f\cdot \nabla(He^{-f} )dV \\
&= -\int_M \nabla f\cdot (e^{-f}\nabla H+ H \nabla (e^{-f}) )dV \\
&= -\int_M \nabla f \cdot \nabla H e^{-f} dV - \int_M \nabla f \cdot (e^{-f}( -\nabla f))H dV \\
&= -\int_M \nabla f \cdot \nabla H e^{-f} dV + \int_M |\nabla f|^2 H e^{-f} dV
\end{split}$$

Move the second term to the left and you are done.

Comment: You are really my saviour.